# “Proof” that $\frac{1}{7}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, infinity, fake-proofs

Sketched this out this morning and it’s been bugging me:

1. If we enumerate ℚ with each element as its decimal expansion, we know that any new number we make a la the old diagonalization trick must be irrational, else we’d have a reductio proving ℚ‘s uncountability
2. This is true irrespective of which enumeration/method of “tweaking” the diagonal we pick
3. So make the following map for  the digits of the diagonal:

- $0 \rightarrow 1$
- $1,2 \rightarrow 4$
- $3,4 \rightarrow 2$
- $5,6 \rightarrow 8$
- $7 \rightarrow 5$
- $9 \rightarrow 7$

4. Then pick an enumeration which cycles through ℚ in a way that guarantees the above digits repeat when we apply the map

Clearly this is me being dumb somewhere but I’m not sure where exactly?

Comment: Why should 4. be possible?

Comment: Ah I see, I was going to say “pick your favourite enumeration and then tweak the numbers to fit the pattern as they come up” but then we lose the guarantee that they’re rational don’t we

Comment: That won't be a complete set $\mathbb{Q}$ because $1/7$  can't fit in it anywhere

Comment: Tweaking one digit of a rational number still keeps it rational, but that new number will already be present on the list somewhere else, while the old number has gone missing. So you no longer have an enumeration of Q. Rearranging the enumeration order is ok, as long as you don't push some number infinitely far down the list, as that is essentially the same as leaving it off the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At some point, there *will be* $\frac 1 7 = 0.\overline{142857}$ in your enumeration of $\mathbb Q$. At that point you have to pick a digit in your new number that makes sure it is not equal to $\frac 1 7$, rendering step $4$ impossible.

Tweaking your enumeration on the go to avoid hitting $0.\overline{142857}$ indefinitely you will end up with an enumeration of (a subset of) $\mathbb Q\setminus\{\tfrac 1 7\}$. Not being on that list doesn't prove irrationality. It just proves your new number is irrational or equal to a rational number not on the list, like $\frac 1 7$.

Comment: Of course, obvious now in retrospect. Thanks!